# How to avoid GET service calls getting cancelled in Angular 4

Tags: angular, aem

I have a component based architecture where all the components gets loaded on page load. There are around 10 to 15 service calls on page load, out of which few of them gets cancelled. I tried using subscribe and promise. While using promise a second call is happening on cancellation. Is there anyways to avoid this cancellation calls.

AEM is tagged as it is a Angular+AEM architecture.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First, is there any way you can replicate this outside of AEM? any code samples? Second, What do you mean by `cancelled`? and how did you figure it was `cancelled` ?

Comment: In the browser the service call status shows as cancelled. It neither goes to success scenario nor to error scenario. I think this issue can occur in Non AEM projects too. If there are multiple service call getting called (for eg 20-30)  some calls have the probability to get cancelled if each service call takes around 1s to execute.

Comment: Can you create a simple example to replicate this on https://stackblitz.com/ or any other IDE that supports angular?